# How can I convert the html encode symbols to their actual characters?

Tags: c#, string, .net-4.0, encode

I'm using the `WebClient.DownloadString` method to GET a response from a website.

Sometimes, the returned string will contain the `'` symbol as it's code: `n#39` (or similar, I'm recalling it from memory).

I've used the `String.Replace` method to replace any occurrences, but maybe there's a built in method that let's me convert these encoding's to the actual character.

Does this exist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can do it using HttpUtility.HtmlDecode() method

```
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(myEncodedString)
```

p.s. You'll need to refer the System.Web.dll assembly in your project.

See this for details

- [MSDN: HttpUtility.HtmlDecode Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be what I'm looking for. It says this method resides in the System.Web namespace, yet I can't seem to find it. I'm making a Winforms application.

Comment: You'll need to refer the  System.Web.dll assembly in your project.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was my application was targeting the ClientFramework. I changed it to the full version and now I can reference the System.Web.dll file. You should add that to your answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx)